# Connecting my vagrant and another VM in VirtualBox

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

For my web development, I use a vagrant install to run a local instance of the website with the following config:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "scotch/box"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 4567, guest: 80
  config.vm.hostname = "some-website"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/public", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh", :args => "some-website", privileged: false

end
```

This website is accessible in the browser on the specified IP.
However, I also have VM's for cross browser testing and these VM's don't have access to the IP address of the Vagrant box.

I need them to connect, because I want to do cross browser testing on that locally running vagrant box.

A couple of StackOverflow searches gave me the option of changing the `private_network` to a `public_network`, but then I can't access the IP anymore.

Also adding `virtualbox__intnet: true` doesn't work.

Would anyone be able to come up with a solution for this? It would be great if I could access the IP from the IE9 VM, directly into the Vagrant VM.

So, to clarify, currently:

- Laptop can access Vagrant (laptop -> VM)
- IE9 VM can't access Vagrant (VM -!> VM)

What I want:

- Laptop can access Vagrant (laptop -> VM)
- IE9 VM can access Vagrant (VM -> VM)

Comment: can you ping each machine ? by default it should work

Comment: I can ping the VM from both my laptop and the other VM, but I can't connect to it. I.e. it won't show the website I'm working on at all.

Comment: if you have private network, it should really work, meaning you can access http://192.168.33.10:4567 from the 2nd VM. If you have issue it probably means you have firewall in place. you can install nmap or telnet and make sure you can get like `telnet 192.168.33.10 4567` or `nmap -p 4567 192.168.33.10`

Comment: You might be right, let me see if it works with just the IP address, instead of the hostname

Comment: I am pretty sure, private means _not publicly accessible from the global internet. In general, this means your machine gets an address in the private address space._ [see doc](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html) so you can access VMs within your host and within VMs

Comment: You are correct, I've added my solution down below crediting you ;-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As [Frédéric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4296747/fr%c3%a9d%c3%a9ric-henri) pointed out: the private_network is actually accessible from another VM on the same host.

My problem seemed to be WordPress itself and not related to Vagrant or the VM setup.